# calling php script from command line echoes script and doesnt run function

Tags: php, command-line

I have a function in a script that is called if two parameters are detected and i call the script via commandline:

```
php index.php '2422244' 'Master chief'
```

My problem is the script is echoed and the function not being called. what could be the problem?

UPDATE: index.php

```
 <?
  if (isset($argv[1])) {
    if(isset($argv[2]) {
       $start = doSomething();
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: check weather php stort tag open is enable or not in your php.ini for cli

Comment: short_open_tag = On in php.ini. Is there another reference specifically for command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In many cases it is caused by a missing 
`<?php` 
at the start of the php file.

Comment: using short tags. had set them to on in my php.ini

Comment: @user3682205 Do you have any luck not using shorttags? Maybe the configuration is not working properly for some reason

Comment: lolI cant believe it was the short tags. Had it on in php.ini

Answer (score 0):

Adjust `php index.php '2422244' 'Master chief'` to `php index.php 2422244 Master chief`

And if you have set short tags to `ON` make sure you restart your server

`service apache2 restart` depending on the server your running